# Fatal: initialStackPointer must be set , shared:ERROR

Tags: emscripten, emsdk, emcc

I want to build bananabread c++ project with emscripten.

I added BINARYEN_ROOT intro ./emscripten .

I also build BINARYEN.

```
LLVM_ROOT = '/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/emsdk-demos/emsdk/emsdk/fastcomp/bin'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = '/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/emsdk-demos/emsdk/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten'
EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER = '/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/emsdk-demos/emsdk/emsdk/fastcomp/bin/optimizer'
NODE_JS = '/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/emsdk-demos/emsdk/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node'
BINARYEN_ROOT = '/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/emsdk-demos/emsdk/emsdk/binaryen/tag-1.38.31'
```

**Erro log :**

> Fatal: initialStackPointer must be set shared:ERROR:
>   '/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/emsdk-demos/emsdk/emsdk/binaryen/tag-1.38.31/bin/wasm-emscripten-finalize
>   /var/folders/hf/pk7l6fn14pj6qft1ns016bqh0000gn/T/emscripten_temp_oiJjbb/tmpDk949v.wasm
>   -o /var/folders/hf/pk7l6fn14pj6qft1ns016bqh0000gn/T/emscripten_temp_oiJjbb/tmpDk949v.wasm.o.wasm
>   --detect-features --global-base=1024' failed (1) FAIL: Compilation failed! make: *** [client] Error 1

**My src is single file :**

```
 // Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow *window;

// Include GLM
#include "glm.hpp"
using namespace glm;

int main(void)
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    do
    {
        // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
                 glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

**My Makefile :**

> ```
>  LDFLAGS=-O1 --llvm-opts 2
>
> test:
>   mkdir -p build
>   emcc tutorial01.cpp \
>   -s USE_GLFW=3 \
>   $(SDLFLAGS) \
>   -lGL \
>   -I/Volumes/POMOCNI/WWW-HTDOCS/cpp/openglTutorials/ogl/external/glm-0.9.7.1/glm \
>   -std=c++14 \
>   -o web/test.html \
>   -g
> ```