# Difference between add_compile_options and add_link_options also flags each option supports

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, linker, linker-flags

I've been using a `.bat` file to build my applications for years. Recently, switched to CMake for it's elegancy and I ran into a situation where I had to guess the flags that I should put into CMake's `add_link_options` and `add_compile_options`

Example flags that I've used in my BAT file,

```
-s WASM=1 --bind -s MODULARIZE=1
```

And, In CMake this flags have become (After trial and error),

```
add_compile_options("SHELL: -s WASM=1")
add_link_options("SHELL: --bind")
add_link_options("SHELL: -s MODULARIZE=1")
```

Honestly, I can't find any information regards flags that `add_link_options` and `add_compile_options`  supports.

I know what is a linker is but lost when it comes to `add_link_options` or linker flags.

I'm used to compile everything in single line and now in **CMake** everything appear to be involve separate steps.

Comment: Nothing. You should not be using those, but the `target_*` variants. But more generally, read a good guide such as https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

Comment: I have target_* variants too and since I have multiple targets I have common flags that has to be shared among them. But either way, be it target or non-target, I still have no idea what to do regarding flags.

Comment: When you run `make clean && make VERBOSE=1`, does it show compiling and linking as two separate steps?  Does it show `--bind` in the linker command and `WASM=1` in the compiler command?  Commands run with `-c` are compilation, not linking.  It seems to me that maybe all 3 options you're passing belong to the compiler phase, but I could be wrong.  It would help if you tell us if your project is building OK now, or if there is a problem, what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem is, but here is a full working sample from a Wasm project that sets project-wide strict mode and disabling of exception support:

```
if (EMSCRIPTEN)
    add_compile_options(-fno-exceptions "SHELL:-s STRICT=1")
    add_link_options("SHELL:-s STRICT=1")
endif()
```

Note in particular that, as it has a `[compile+link]` marker in the [emscripten settings](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js), `-s STRICT=1` has to be used both for compiling and for linking, thus it appears in each.

The `if(EMSCRIPTEN)` around is there because this project can also be built for Windows and Linux.

Comment: while -s STRICT=1  behaves so other flags can't be used that way. I just need to know which flags I should pass at compile and linker stages.

Comment: Simply look them up in the documentation. Clang documentation is here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html and emscripten flags documentation is here: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js

Comment: Have you checked? What make you thinks that I didn't checked those? I did and they contains no info.

Comment: The Github one does contains them. I initially used their website docs. Now everything clear. If you can write answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Overall emscripten documentation is good, but a few technical details are harder to find than they should be. The link for that page is on [EMCC reference](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html), about 2 pages down the top, in the documentation for `-s OPTION[=VALUE]`.

Comment: When one shall use quoted string and when one may provide options verbatim? Where did "SHELL: " syntax come from?

Comment: @ivan_onys> straight from [the documentation of add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html)

Answer (score 0):

The options you can pass to the compiler or linker depends on which compiler or linker you use.  For example if you fork GCC and add a `-Wstackoverflow-copy-pasta` option, you can pass that option to `add_compile_options()`, but other people using standard GCC cannot.

So the answer to your question seems to be, read your compiler and linker documentation.

Comment: I'm using Emscripten and it uses Clang I believe.

Comment: I have read documentation and it lacks this info that's why I posted this question in first place.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the specific flags from your old .bat files that you're not sure how to integrate in CMake?  Maybe also try `make VERBOSE=1` with your CMake project to see what options it is passing where, and compare those with your old .bat files.

Comment: I already  have integrated everything but just feel uncomfortable with guessing game. I will edit and include flags.

Comment: I just added them to post.

Comment: @jeffbRTC: As far as I understand from the documentation, Emscripten  uses `emcc` as a compiler and as a linker. According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53133873/3440745), `-s` is a **linker** option.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  emcc use Clang and -s is not just a linker option because -s WASM=1 isn't